# If a stationary ball of neutrinos were released at the equator, what orbit would it take?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, neutrinos

Students are traditionally asked how long it would take an object to fall through the "center" of the earth and reach the other side. In the demonstrations which I have seen, the initial velocity of the object due to the rotation of the earth is not taken into consideration.

Suppose one had a solid ball of "neutrino-ium" (or perhaps dark matter) stationary at the earth's surface at the equator which one releases and allows to fall through the earth.

Assuming a spherical earth of constant density, into what sort of orbit would the ball settle?

Because of the variation in gravity during the trajectory, I doubt that standard equations of orbital mechanics will be sufficient to determine the orbit, so I am at a loss.

Comment: The equations are sufficient assuming you know the mass distribution inside the Earth; if you don't, you can make various approximations. But in any case the neutrinos will oscillate around the center of the Earth (assuming spherical symmetry).

Comment: Related to [126077](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/126077/why-are-these-periods-the-same-a-low-earth-orbit-and-oscillations-through-the-c); also see [this](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mechanics/earthole.html#c1), crudely assuming a uniform earth and ignoring frame-dragging effects of the earth's rotation, of course, as a zeroth order approximation...

Comment: How massive is the ball??

Comment: @CountTo10 Good point. Let's say 1 kg, or any amount insignificant in comparison to the mass of the earth.

Comment: If it is released from rest, why should it fall into any orbit at all?

Comment: By "at rest" I meant with respect to some fixed location on the surface, giving it a velocity vector orthogonal to the gravitational force vector. This is why I specified its location at the equator. The orbit would depend upon its initial latitude.

Comment: The ball has an initial horizontal velocity because of the earth's rotation. The traditional exercise, at least as I have seen it presented, ignores this initial velocity and assumes the ball is falling down a perfectly vertical shaft which passes through the center of the earth. Such a ball would bounce from one wall of the shaft to the other if one considers its initial velocity perpendicular to the gravitational force.

Comment: @CosmasZachos My apologies. I responded to your comment but forgot to address it to you.

Comment: My apologies, I misread the tangential velocity spec. Since the gravity force is central, angular momentum is conserved, so take it to be $l\equiv L/m=\dot{\theta} r^2$ contributing a centrifugal barrier term $m l^2/(2r^2)$ to the gravity potential,  thus opposing  the plain oscillator force.

Comment: [Somewhat related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/402565/sudden-release-of-condensate-from-trap-ermakov-equation-scaling-solution).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the force is central, angular momentum is conserved, and so the angular motion can be solved in terms of the radial motion. Using the conventions of the [spinless earth](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mechanics/earthole.html#c1) starting point you mention, that is $\omega^2=g/R$, for $R$ the radius thereof, we see the earth's motion is a small perturbation, as the 24hrs period is so much larger than the canonical 2π/ω=84.5 mins. In fact, the centrifugal barrier will eject the neutrino ball so the effective period is more like half the spinless case. It will come up ahead of where it was released---it will have effectively spun faster than the earth.

The conserved angular momentum is $L=m r^2 \dot{\theta}$, which it pays to re-write in terms of a dimensionless variable *a*. The vanishing *a* 
limit is the spinless earth, while *a*=2 corresponds to the notional earth spinning so fast as to give the neutrino ball the escape velocity. The particle's mass *m* is a canard that factors out.
$$
L\equiv \sqrt{a} m \omega R^2 .
$$
Thus, given $r(t)$, integrating $\dot{\theta}=L/(mr^2)= \sqrt{a}  \omega R^2/r(t)^2$ completely specifies the angular motion. For the "real" earth, $\dot{\theta}_R/\omega=\sqrt{a}\sim 0.06$, *small*.

In these variables, the energy of the ball for $r\leq R$ (only!) is 
$$
E=\frac{m\dot{r}^2}{2}+\frac{mg}{2R} r^2+\frac{m a\omega^2R^4}{2r^2} .
$$

The equation of motion then, in terms of the dimensionless *x* = *r/R* is
the nonlinear *Ermakov equation*
$$
\ddot{x} = -\omega^2 x + \frac{a \omega^2}{x^3},
$$
whose first integral is $~~\dot{x}^2/\omega^2+x^2+a/x^2=2E/(\omega^2 mR^2)=1+a$.

Consider the solution
$$
x=\sqrt{\sin^2(\omega t +\pi/2) +  a/(1-a) } ~~ \sqrt{1-a} .
$$
It has a suitable $a\to 0$ limit, the spinless oscillation, $r=R\sin (\omega t +\pi/2)$, and *x(t=0)*=1. Nevertheless, it will have exactly the same 84.5 min period as the spinless case, since *a* and *ω* are independent. It should not be a surprise the periodic motion amounts to a closed [elliptic orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Polar_form_relative_to_focus),     of course: it is just an orbit in a harmonic potential, until surfacing (and splicing into a Kepler potential...).

It is also apparent that the neutrino ball will *never* get to the center, as the minimum *r* will be $\sim R \sqrt{a}$ for small *a*, the effective centrifugal barrier. For the "real" earth, this perigee would be ~0.06 *R*.

---

Perhaps somebody with graphics juices and time to lavish could plot the integrated *r* - *θ* orbits viewed from the North pole. Note the enormous eccentricity: $e\sim 1-2 \sqrt{a}$ !